# c# screen scraping and getting all the cookies for secured access to a website

Tags: c#, cookies, httpwebrequest, httpresponse

I'm trying to access a website through c# program. There seems to be three cookies needed to access the website yet I only receive two in my cookie container so when I try to access other parts the website I can't. I first do a GET then a POST. The reason I programmed it this way because it seemed from the Chrome Dev tools I determined that it first used a GET for the first two and then a POST to login and get the third one. The POST shows a 302 Moved Temporarily and then right after that it's a redirect. Which I believe is the reason I can't obtain the last cookie can anyone shed any light?

```
                 cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
        string formParams = string.Format("USERNAME={0}&PASSWORD={1}", username, password);

        Console.Write(" \n 1st count before anything : " + cookieJar.Count + "\n");  // 0 cookies
        //First go to the login page to obtain cookies
        HttpWebRequest loginRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://server.com/login/login.jsp");

        loginRequest.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
        //.Connection = "keep-alive";
        loginRequest.Method = "GET";
        loginRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        loginRequest.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
        loginRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;



        HttpWebResponse loginResponse = (HttpWebResponse)loginRequest.GetResponse();
       Console.Write(" \n 2nd count after first response : " + cookieJar.Count + "\n"); // Only 2 are recorded.

    //Create another request to actually log into website
          HttpWebRequest doLogin = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://server.com/login/login.jsp");

        doLogin.Method = "POST";
        doLogin.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        doLogin.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams);
        doLogin.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        using (Stream os = doLogin.GetRequestStream())
        {
            os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
    oLogin.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
        doLogin.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36";
        doLogin.Referer = "https://server.com/login/login.jsp";

        HttpWebResponse Response = (HttpWebResponse)doLogin.GetResponse();
```

Console.Write(" \n 3rd count after second repsonse : " + cookieJar.Count + "\n"); // still two

Comment: I have been fighting with this as well for some other things.  You may need to actually add the cookies you get from the response to your cookie object.  cookieJar.Add(loginResponse.Cookies);

Comment: Thank you kind sir for the reply! Alas, That's not it. Even when I do  Console.Write(Response.Headers) It only replies with two cookies in the Set-Cookie header. I still did try your solution yet it didn't do anything. This is so perplexing...... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HttpWebRequest had a problem with cookies.

The problem was that a cookie that was assigned to "server.com" would be changed to ".server.com".  However, "server.com" did not match ".server.com".

If you are using a framework older than (I think it is  3) you are probably experiencing this problem.

The work around is to use e.g. "www.server.com" in your request, this will match cookies assigned to ".server.com".

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I'm actually on framework 4. Yet i tried it anyway and yet I can't use it because if I add www. to the front I cannot communicate with the server. Is there another way to determine if this is the issue( a source link?) . If that's really the issue I'd need to have an entirely different approach....

Comment: It should not be a problem in framework 4.  I use it all the time on at thousand different websites.  I recommend that you use Fiddler2 to figure out what exactly you are requesting and what responses you get.

Comment: Thank you for the fiddler tip. I figured it out. :)